# selectize.js and vue.js 2 ajax loaded optons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, selectize.js

I'm using vuejs@2.3.3, selectize@0.12.4, [vue2-selectize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-selectize).
I have a pretty big form with a few select inputs.
All options are loaded by ajax into a one property, which is initialized with a demo data before being replaced by ajax data:

```
addTrackData : {

    styles : [
        { id: 1, title: 'style 1' },
        { id: 2, title: 'style 3' },
        { id: 3, title: 'style 2' },
    ],
    authors: [
        {inn: '111', name: 'demo 1'},
        {inn: '222', name: 'demo 2'},
        {inn: '333', name: 'demo 3'}
    ]
    ....
},
```

And I've got 2 problems:

1) If I use settings in this way, options doesn't loads at all:

```
<selectize v-model="form.data.authors[i]['id']" :settings="selectize.authors"></selectize>

selectize: {
    authors: {
        valueField: 'inn',
        labelField: 'name',
        searchField: ['name', 'inn'],
        options: this.addTrackData.authors // that doesn't works, but hard coded array works
    }
}
```

Because of error `Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'authors' of undefined"`.
Both `this.addTrackData.authors` and `addTrackData.authors` makes this error.

But this way works:

```
<selectize v-model="form.data.authors[i]['id']"
    :settings=" {
        valueField: 'inn',
        labelField: 'name',
        searchField: ['name', 'inn'],
        options: addTrackData.authors, // It works, but looks too ugly! 
    }" >
</selectize>
```

2) Options are not reactive - when ajax data comes, all selects elements still shows a demo data. And I have no idea how to update them all...

**UPDATE**

Second problem could be fixed with If Conditional and empty initial array:

```
<selectize v-if="addTrackData.authors.length" v-model="form.data.authors[i]['id']"
    :settings=" {
        valueField: 'inn',
        labelField: 'name',
        searchField: ['name', 'inn'],
        options: addTrackData.authors, // It works, but looks too ugly! 
    }" >
</selectize>

addTrackData : {
    styles : [],
    authors: []
    ....
}
```

But the first problem still makes me cry

Comment: When data comes from server, try setting your `addTrackData` using `this.$set(this, 'addTrackData', receivedData)`.

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: another thing you can try is putting your `addTrackData.authors` in a **computed property** and using its reference in your selectize's setting.

Comment: unfortunately, selectize don't want to redraw select anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just read the source code of `vue2-selectize` and noticed that it's watch code for `options` key is incorrect.

his code is this way:

```
watch: {
  value() {
    this.setValue()
  },
  options (value, old) {
    if (this.$el.selectize && !equal(value, old)) {
      this.$el.selectize.clearOptions()
      this.$el.selectize.addOption(this.current)
      this.$el.selectize.refreshOptions(false)
      this.setValue()
    }
  }
},
```

while it should be this way to work:

```
watch: {
  value() {
    this.setValue()
  },
  options (value, old) {
    if (this.$el.selectize && !equal(value, old)) {
      this.$el.selectize.clear();
      this.$el.selectize.clearOptions();
      var vm = this;
      this.$el.selectize.load(function(callback) {
        callback(vm.current);
      });
      this.$el.selectize.refreshOptions(false);
      this.setValue();
    }
  }
},
```

I just prepared a hacky way to make it working but I dont encourage you using it in production.

Here is the fiddle's link: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadm/h8p97hm7/

I'll try to send a pull request to his creator as soon as possible but until that time, your solution is already the only possible solution.

Comment: I just want to add my [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/n4mz318x/) as a possible work-around. But I would also recommend to fork the vue2-selectize and improve the watch part.

Comment: Thanks @AWolf , your fiddle is also suggesting a clean way to do it. I think also that it's necessary to fork and improve `vue2-selectize` asap. I'll send a pull request for it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you guys! Looks like there is no way to just using `options: this.addTrackData.authors` ?